# How do I perform SQL Join equivalent functionality in sphinx?

Tags: mysql, join, full-text-search, sphinx

Can anyone tell me how can we achieve the functionality of SQL join in **sphinx search**?
I want to index few columns from table1 and few from table2.

Tables are in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1° as Barryhunter answer

```
sql_query = SELECT t1.id,t1...., t2....  FROM table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON ....
```

2° if one-to-many

```
sql_query = SELECT t1.id,t1...., group_concat(t2.foo) ASt 2_foo, .  FROM table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON .... GROUP BY t1.id
```

group_concat has length limitation but sphinx is  marvellous

```
sql_query = SELECT t1.id,t1....,.  FROM table1 AS t1;

sql_joined_field =  t2_foo from query;\  
SELECT t2.rel_t1_id  , t2.foo\ 
FROM table2` AS t2\
ORDER by t2.rel_t1_id ASC
```

As my English is poor, read this is probably more clear
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-sql-joined-field.html

sql_joined_field =  t2_foo  would add one more "searchable" field called t2_foo. In this field you retrieve t2.foo content (like the group concat but seperated by space)

The first column must be the id matching to t1.id in your sql_query

ORDER by theID ASC is mandatory

In same idea  you can use  mva for multiple value in an attribute
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-sql-attr-multi.html

```
sql_attr_multi = uint tag from query; \
SELECT id, tag FROM tags
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please briefly describe me how `sql_joined_field` works? Found this thing while googling also, but couldn't understand. I'm newbie to sphinx. @Moosh

Comment: wait for a barryhunter note.  He always has good points on what I say :-)

Comment: To be honest not really sure I can explain any better than the example in teh documentation, and the example provided here.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a join in the `sql_query`, its just a standard MySQL query, that indexer runs and indexes the output. the MySQL server just needs to run it.

```
sql_query = SELECT id,t.name,o.test FROM table1 t INNER JOIN other o USING (id)
```